# Trajectory interpolation and derivative

Tags: c++, spline

I'm working on the analysis of a particle's trajectory in a 2D plane. This trajectory typically consists of 5 to 50 (in rare cases more) points (discrete integer coordinates). I have already matched the points of my dataset to form a trajectory (thus I have time resolution).
I'd like to perform some analysis on the curvature of this trajectory, unfortunately the analysis framework I'm using has no support for fitting a trajectory. From what I heard one can use splines/bezier curves for getting this done but I'd like your opinion and/or suggestions what to use.
As this is only an optional part of my work I can not invest a vast amount of time for implementing a solution on my own or understanding a complex framework. The solution has to be as simple as possible.

Let me specify the features I need from a possible library:
- create trajectory from varying number of points
- as the points are discrete it should interpolate their position; no need for exact matches for all points as long as the resulting distance between trajectory and point is less than a threshold
- it is essential that the library can yield the **derivative** of the trajectory for any given point
- it would be beneficial if the library could report a quality level (like chiSquare for fits) of the interpolation

**EDIT:** After reading the comments I'd like to add some more:
It is not necessary that the trajectory exactly matches the points. The points are created from values of a pixel matrix and thus they form a discrete matrix of coordinates with a space resolution limited by the number of pixel per given distance. Therefore the points (which are placed at the center of the firing pixel) do not (exactly) match the actual trajectory of the particle. Either interpolation or fit is fine for me as long as the solution can cope with a trajectory which may/most probably will be neither bijective nor injective.
Thus most traditional fit approaches (like fitting with polynomials or exponential functions using a least squares fit) can't fulfil my criterias.
Additionaly all traditional fit approaches I have tried yield a function which seems to describe the trajectory quite well but when looking at their first derivative (or at higher resolution) one can find numerous "micro-oscillations" which (from my interpretation) are a result of fitting non-straight functions to (nearly) straight parts of the trajectory.

**Edit2:** There has been some discussion in the comments, what those trajectories may look like. Essentially thay may have any shape, length and "curlyness", although I try to exclude trajectories which overlap or cross in the previous steps. I have included two examples below; ignore the colored boxes, they're just a representation of the values of the raw pixel matrix. The black, circular dots are the points which I'd like to match to a trajectory, as you can see they are always centered to the pixels and therefore may have only discrete (integer) values.

[image: ex1]
[image: ex2]

Thanks in advance for any help & contribution!

Comment: An interpolant is actually coincident with your points - that is the definition of interpolant so when you say that you dont need exact matches it is kind of contradictory. Does this mean you only require the curve to interpolate a subset of points and approximate the remainder with a certain accuracy? You cant really have a quality of interpolation as the error at interpolation points is zero.

Comment: If you don't need it to go through the points you might consider using non-linear least squares. This will give you a best-fit polynomial through the points.

Comment: @infact You would have trouble fitting a figure of 8 trajectory using polynomials

Comment: I'm not so sure, a figure of eight like [cos(x),sin(x)cos(x)] is a smooth function anyway.

Comment: The problem with traditional fit approaches using polynoms/sinusoidal/exp/gauss functions is that they yield a fit that has micro-oscillations (especially when the trajectory moves straight horizontal for some time), which in turn yield a first derivative that is way off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MIGHT be the way to go

http://alglib.codeplex.com/

From your description I would say that a parametric spline interpolation may suit your requirements. I have not used the above library myself, but it does have support for spline interpolation.  Using an interpolant means you will not have to worry about goodness of fit - the curve will pass through every point that you give it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using matrix libraries, [linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29) is the easiest solution (look at the end of the General Problem section for the equation to use). You can also use [linear/polynomial regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to solve something like this.

Linear least squares will always give the best solution, but it's not scalable, because matrix multiplication is moderately expensive. Regression is an iterative heuristic method, so you can just run it until you have a "sufficiently good" answer. I've seen guidelines for the cutoff at about 1000-10000 dimensions in your data. So, with your data set, I'd recommend linear least squares, unless you decide to make them highly dimensioned for some reason.

Comment: What happens if his trajectory is a closed loop?? An elliptic orbit for example??? Or let us say that he has 2 distinct Y values for identical X values. This approach will simply break down - it will only work for a very limited type type of data set ie distinct pairs of (x,y). Given that this is a trajectory he is modelling, what if the curve needs to travel from a point (x,y) = (100,200) to (x_1,y_1) = (50,100) ?? Linear least squares with a polynomial cant handle this.

Comment: I don't know exactly what he's doing, but given that we're dealing with a particle's trajectory, it's not unlikely that the problem is within the constraints of linear least squares. However, I noted that more complex problems, such as with high dimensions/orbitals rather than trajectory, are handled through polynomial regression.

Comment: Oh yes I agree, to a very specific ordered set of unique (unique abscissae i mean) data your method would be perfectly acceptable. But I would think this highly unlikely in the case with a 2-D plane trajectory. That is just my opinion though based on the wording of the OP and there is not really enough info in the OP to say one way or the other.